# How can you change the alignment of the text in powerpoint text box using officer package. (top/middle/bottom)?

Tags: r, officer

I am using the `officer` package to write text and tables to a powerpoint. I was wondering if anyone knows how to change the description variable below so that the text is aligned top (vs middle/bottom) in the textbox when it gets written to the powerpoint?

```
description <- fpar(ftext("Campaign Insights", fp_text(color = "#545759", font.size = 14, font.family =fontname)))

title <-  fpar(ftext("Campaign: Overall Metric Results ", fp_text(color = "White", font.size = 20, font.family ="Avenir Next LT Pro Demi", bold = T)))
add_slide(my_pres,layout = "7_Custom Layout", master = "Office Theme") %>%
  ph_with(ft, location = ph_location(left =0.17 , top = 1.59, width = 9.16, height = .3))%>%
  ph_with(chart, location = ph_location(left = 0.17, top = 1.58, width = 9.33, height = 4))%>%
  ph_with(title, location = ph_location(left = 0.22, top = 0, width = 9.49, height = .6))%>%
  ph_with(paragraph, location = ph_location(left = 0.36, top = 5, width = 1.5, height = .5 ))%>%
  ph_with(description, location = ph_location(left = 0.22, top = 0.6, width = 9.49, height = 1, anchor = "topleft"))
```

Comment: why don't you do it in the template? it seems you only want to use manual coordinates with ph_location but you could instead use placeholders defined in the template and benefit from their settings (top/middle/bottom alignement for example)